# Django filter comparing DateTimeField with today's date does not work

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Quite strangely, cannot figure this out after trying for sometime:

Trying to fetch a model instance from the Model `InputsApproval`

```
todays_input = InputsApproval.objects.filter(user=request.user,
                                  input_time__date=datetime.date.today()).first()
```

(where `input_time` is a `DateTimeField`)

but `todays_input` is returned as `None` when I know that there is one record for the logged in user that has today's date (and is also visible from the django admin)

In fact, to debug this, I created a for loop to loop through all the records and compare with today's date and it does return `True` for that one record (but somehow the filter query keeps returning `None`):

```
all_records_for_current_user = InputsApproval.objects.filter(user=request.user)

for record in all_records_for_current_user:
    print('today() returns', datetime.date.today())
    print('date for this record is', record.input_time.date())
    print ('Does it match?', datetime.date.today() == record.input_time.date())
```

Comment: Can you share the output of your script for the records that should be returned? Do you have `USE_TZ=True` in your settings and if you do what is `TIME_ZONE`?

Comment: @IainShelvington (thanks for trying to help) The filter query should return a model instance whereas it returns `None`. The for loop is only to debug this issue and it does return 2021-04-17, 2021-04-17, True for one record. Yeah `USE_TZ` is at the default setting (i.e `True`). `TIME_ZONE` is set to `America/New_York`

Comment: Can you share the output of this values query for the record you are expecting? `InputsApproval.objects.values('input_time', 'input_time__date')`

Comment: can  you ignore user and filter only date time once it is strange it is not working on your machine.

Comment: @IainShelvington - I think you asked the right question :) 


`<QuerySet [{'input_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 17, 4, 7, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'input_time__date': None},
{'input_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 16, 5, 6, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'input_time__date': None}]>`

The returned dates are `None` (which wasn't the case when I did `.date()` in the for loop). I wonder why though. Also, tzinfo says `UTC` whereas we are using `America/New_York` in the TIME_ZONE (seems like I also need to make it timezone aware somewhere).

Comment: @daneilJames thanks - I did try ignoring the user - seems like the issue is with `__date`

Comment: Shall I mention ans below so it might be easier for others?

Comment: @Anupam have you use django utils. timezone or python date time ?